# NHibernate non-unique child collection to load eagerly (one-to-many or many-to-many)

Tags: nhibernate, join, many-to-many, one-to-many, eager-loading

- when I use one-to-many relations, I keep getting:

  > collection is not associated with any session

  errors when loading eagerly, and not getting any children if I load lazily.
- when using many-to-many, I get unnecessary and wrong joins.

The data scheme is like this:

> Item:
>
> - int ID (PK)
> - string Name
> - int StorageId (FK Storage, non-unique usage)

> Storage  (ignored in mapping):
>
> - int ID (PK)
>
>   - string Name

> TransporterToStorage (contains info, not only link table):
>
> - int ID (PK)
>
>   - int StorageId (FK Storage)
>   - int TransporterId (FK Transporter)
>   - string TransportLineName

> Transporter (ignored in mapping):
>
> - int ID (PK)
>
>   - string Name

Item shall be represented by a C# / NHibernate class, with an additional collection property `TransportersToStorage`, containing 0-n entries. Due to performance reasons, I want to map only the `Item.StorageId` to the `TransporterToStorage.StorageId` and ignore the `Storage` table, which holds the primary key for both.

```
<bag name="TransportersToStorages" ... >
<key property-ref="StorageId" unique="false" ... />
<one-to-many class="TransporterToStorage" column="StorageId" ... />
</bag>
```

one-to-many seems to violate some NHibernate rules, because equal `TransporterToStorage` entries can belong to multiple Items. This is probably the cause of the:

> collection is not associated with any session

error on eager loading.

The specific query is like (quick pseudo HQL, but actually done with Criteria):

```
select Item inner join fetch TransporterToStorage tts 
where tts.TransporterId = :p1 and tts.StorageId in (:p2, :p3, :p4)
```

Can many-to-many or a similar association be done with only one join in the SQL sent to the database?

What is best to map this?

The child collection shall be loaded lazily by default (meaning: not at all), and eagerly in the given case.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: I gave it up, since the application I'm working with makes little use of NHibernate object relations, and it is almost impossible to refactor it all within little time. Currently, most objects are designed like the "Item" above, with only another object's ID, and a top layer arranges all loading, updating of related objects, collection etc. by separate queries (formerly native SQL, increasingly HQL/Criteria). Changing this may become a task in the not-so-distant future.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a session management problem here, I suspect your session is closed BEFORE you access your lazy/eager loaded children. You might need to change the way you manage your sessions or load parent/children into a DTO and return this from your method.

Without knowing more about the way you are handling sessions a more definitive answer is difficult.